# DocuSign Payment Field Template

Tags: php, docusignapi

I have a DocuSign template

i have payment field there and i am using formula (i had to set there currency because is mandatory but i want to change it using API call)

I am using PHP and docusign-php-client to integrate
I am successfully manage to update the formula but i want to change payment_details  currency and i am not able to do this

```
$client->setTabs((new Tabs)
            ->setNumberTabs([(new Number())->setTabLabel('TOTAL_PRICE')->setValue(1000)])
            ->setFormulaTabs([(new FormulaTab())
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->setFormula('([TOTAL_PRICE]) * 3')
                ->setRoundDecimalPlaces(2)
                ->setTabLabel('PAYMENT_PRICE')
                ->setPaymentDetails((new PaymentDetails())
                    ->setCurrencyCode('USD')
                    ->setLineItems([
                        (new PaymentLineItem())
                            ->setName('TOTAL_PRICE')
                            ->setAmountReference('TOTAL_PRICE')
                    ])
                    ->setGatewayAccountId('xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx')
                )
                ->setXPosition(482)   // i was testing if i can add dynamic field but i cannot
                ->setYPosition(798)
            ])
        );
```

Formula is updated when document is creating

Questions:

1. Why setPaymentDetails is ignored (i've set in template currency: EUR and I want to change it to USD using API call)?
2. Is this possible to add field dynamically to existing template?

EDIT: I figured out point 2:
i needed to add

```
                ->setDocumentId(1)
                ->setPageNumber(1)
```

to make it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, setPaymentDetails takes JSON, like this:

```
    $payment_details = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\PaymentDetails([
        'gateway_account_id' => $args['gateway_account_id'],
        'currency_code' => "USD",
        'gateway_name' => $args['gateway_name'],
        'line_items' => [$payment_line_iteml1, $payment_line_iteml2]]);
```

So, I'm not sure about the way you're making separate calls for each argument.
See code example here:
https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant/blob/master/src/EG014CollectPayment.php